# SQL views - cannot create view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hy, i'm new on stackoverflow.

I have problem with creating a view in SQL.
Here's my code. I'd like to someone help me. 
Thanks.

```
USE AdventureWorksLT2012
GO 
CREATE VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese

AS
SELECT SalesLT.Customer.Title, SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, SalesLT.Customer.LastName, 
        SalesLT.Customer.EmailAddress, SalesLT.Address.AddressLine1, 
         SalesLT.Address.AddressLine2, SalesLT.Address.City
FROM SalesLT.CustomerAddress INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer 
    ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID = SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address 
    ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = SalesLT.Address.AddressID


SELECT FirstName,LastName
FROM viewKupciAdrese

ALTER VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese
AS
SELECT     SalesLT.Customer.Title, SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, SalesLT.Customer.LastName, SalesLT.Customer.EmailAddress, SalesLT.Address.AddressLine1, 
                      SalesLT.Address.AddressLine2, SalesLT.Address.City
FROM         SalesLT.CustomerAddress INNER JOIN
                      SalesLT.Customer ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID = SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                      SalesLT.Address ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = SalesLT.Address.AddressID

DROP VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese
```

And here's an error.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure viewKupciAdrese, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'viewKupciAdrese'.

Comment: You've got multiple statements there. Put a `GO` delimiter after each Data Definition statement (i.e. after `CREATE VIEW ... GO` and `ALTER VIEW ... GO`).

Comment: I tried, nothing happen's .. i just got some new errors -.-

Comment: You also need a GO between your varied SELECT statements ... so it's `CREATE VIEW AS SELECT ... GO SELECT FirstName ... GO ALTER VIEW AS SELECT ... GO DROP VIEW ... GO`

Comment: Thank you, it works. I added GO on 3 places and it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me. Use the delimiter `GO` after any Create View or Alter View statement. I usually throw one in before it as well (common habit).

```
USE AdventureWorksLT2012
GO 

CREATE VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese

AS
SELECT SalesLT.Customer.Title, SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, SalesLT.Customer.LastName, 
        SalesLT.Customer.EmailAddress, SalesLT.Address.AddressLine1, 
         SalesLT.Address.AddressLine2, SalesLT.Address.City
FROM SalesLT.CustomerAddress INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer 
    ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID = SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address 
    ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = SalesLT.Address.AddressID

GO

SELECT FirstName,LastName
FROM viewKupciAdrese

GO

ALTER VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese

AS
SELECT     SalesLT.Customer.Title, SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, SalesLT.Customer.LastName, SalesLT.Customer.EmailAddress, SalesLT.Address.AddressLine1, 
                      SalesLT.Address.AddressLine2, SalesLT.Address.City
FROM         SalesLT.CustomerAddress INNER JOIN
                      SalesLT.Customer ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID = SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                      SalesLT.Address ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = SalesLT.Address.AddressID

GO
DROP VIEW dbo.viewKupciAdrese
```

Comment: Good catch.  It was the view name in the *second* query, not the first.